# Регулярное выражение - поиск постов от даты до 29.10.2018 на PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, регулярные-выражения, дата

Сама задача для виджета Wordpress, необходимо, чтобы он выводился только если пост опубликован позже даты 29.10.2018. Переменная $date выводит дату в формате "November 3, 2018", так вот необходимо соорудить регулярку "если $date раньше 29.10.2018", то return. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Какая регулярка? Она тут не нужна. Делайте запрос в базу с ограничением по дате. Гугл kama wp_query

Comment: Но мне нужно не вывести посты, мне нужно прописать условие в виджете, чтобы он выводился только для тех постов, которые позже такой-то даты.

Comment: вот в коде виджета и надо внести правки, чтобы он из базы вытаскивал только то, что нужно

Comment: Что будете делатьс регуляркой, если виджет выводит 3 записи, и все они не подходят по дате? А подходящие записи есть. Да и вообще, это бред - тащить ненужные записи из базы, а потом их выкусывать из вывода

Comment: Так не виджет же записи выводит. Даже наоборот: записи выводят виджет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то понадобится, проблема решена следующим:

```
$date    = get_the_time( 'Y-m-d', $ID );
$deadline = strtotime('2010-09-29');
if (strtotime($date) < $deadline) return;
```

Но $ID добавляется только если решения для глобальных переменных Wordpress, в противном случае это:

```
$date    = get_the_time( "Y-m-d");
```